SQL Docker Server connection fails unless i directly input password in ASP.NET
I've created an ASP.NET Rest API and I'm trying to write a docker compose for it. I have tried setting it up so that connection is set up from within the compose file, but it seems that host and server name work but not the password? I get the error that password for Login does not match unless I directly input.
Here is my compose file where I set up my host name and password:
version: '3.4'

networks:
  barcodeapp:

services:
  barcodedb:
    container_name: barcode-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - "8002:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=StrongPasswordExample
    networks:
      barcodeapp:

  barcodeapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}barcodeapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: BarcodeAPI/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    depends_on:
     - barcodedb
    environment:
    - DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    - DB_NAME=Barcode_API
    - DB_SA_PASSWORD=StrongPasswordExample
    networks:
      barcodeapp:

And this is the code that does not work, this is the code that makes it so it says wrong password attempted when I check the docker desktop container.
var dbHost = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_HOST");
var dbName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_NAME");
var dbPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_SA_PASSWORD");
var connectionString = $"Data Source={dbHost};Initial Catalog={dbName};User ID=sa;Password={dbPassword};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True";
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BarcodeAPIDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

The weird thing is that if I don't use dbPassword and just write in the password, it works? I'm confused and don't know why I'm getting this error.
Here is the code that works with the only change being the putting in the password directly:
var dbHost = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_HOST");
var dbName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_NAME");
var dbPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_SA_PASSWORD");
var connectionString = $"Data Source={dbHost};Initial Catalog={dbName};User ID=sa;Password=StrongPasswordExample;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True";
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BarcodeAPIDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString));


By debugging with break points i can see that all 3 variables are always null , still trying to figure out why

your yaml seems to be a bit misaligned after the environment: block, could that be the problem?

Aside... the SA_PASSWORD environment variable has been deprecated for quite some time now, you should be using MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD as per the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation.

Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs and from a networking point of view 127.0.0.1, ::1 and localhost all refer to the current container itself. What happens if, instead of DB_HOST=127.0.0.1, you specify DB_HOST=barcode-db?

Also, this may not be a password issue as such... if you watch the container log output for the SQL Server container does it report that the login fails because the database does not exist? Databases have to exist before you can reference them in connection strings, so where does the Barcode_API database get created?
